# Ubuntu touch reverse tethering and click apps/updates

Tags: ubuntu-touch, reverse-tethering

I configured reverse USB tethering between my laptop (with ubuntu 15.04) and my Nexus 4 (with ubuntu touch OTA 5 rev 22).

It works well for most applications, like web browser, GPS navigators, ubuntu-touch.fr webapp, but it does not work when I click on the ubuntu store (which shows an empty page), and for System parameters/updates (which seems to try to connect to something without success).

Wireshark on the usb interface shows that there is no network traffic at all on the usb cable, which is surprising. A wireshark analysis for web navigation, for example, is normal.

It acts as if System parameters/updates forces the connexion to be OTA (data connexion is either wifi or 2G/3G/4G), which is a bug in my opinion: if I want to update my phone, or just access the app store, through the USB connection, I should be able to do it! I finally do not have a clue of what is happening, and where to submit a bug report.

Any idea ?

---

Phone configuration: Nexus 4 with mako OTA 5 rev 22
Laptop configuration: Ubuntu 15.04

USB reverse tethering configuration process (A is the phone side, B the laptop side)

```
A> android-gadget-service enable rndis
   sudo /sbin/ifconfig usb0 10.1.0.1
B> sudo /sbin/ifconfig usb0 10.1.0.2
A> sudo route add default gw 10.1.0.2
B> echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
   sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
A> add nameservers 212.27.40.240 and 212.27.40.241 to /etc/resolv.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

worked well here with revision OTA-8 BQ Aquaris E4.5.
thanks for your mini-tutorial. I add some informations:

## On phone device:

```
android-gadget-service enable rndis
sudo route add default gw your_computer_usb_ip
echo nameserver 8.8.8.8 > /etc/resolvconf/conf.d/tail
resolvconf -u
```

## On computer:

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```